# POST multipart/form-data with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: forms, iphone, asihttprequest

I'm new to ASIHTTPRequest and I have a problem to implement a form.
At the moment I use the following code inside a UIWebForm and everything work fine.

```
    NSString *body = @"\ 
    <html> \ 
    <head> \ 
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; 
charset=iso-8859-1\"> \ 
        </head>   \ 
        <body>\ 
        <form name=\"my_form\" action=\"http://www.server.com/ar? 
ca=11_s&id=22630957\" \ 
        method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"> \ 
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"  value=\"myname\"> \ 
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" value=\"mym...@gmail.com\"> \ 
    <textarea name=\"body\">My message</textarea> \ 
        <input type=checkbox name=\"sendercc\" value=\"0\"> \ 
    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"send\" value=\"Send\"> \ 
        </table> \ 
        </form> \ 
        </body>\ 
        </html>";
```

The (not working) code that should replace the form is the follow:

```
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL: 
[[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.server.com/ar? 
ca=11_s&id=22630957"] autorelease]]; 
        [request setResponseEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]; 
        [request setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat]; 
        [request setPostValue:@"myname" forKey:@"name"]; 
        [request setPostValue:@"mymail@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"]; 
        [request setPostValue:@"My message" forKey:@"body"]; 
        [request setPostValue:@"0" forKey:@"sendercc"]; 
        [request startSynchronous];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you explain more about how it doesn't work? Do you get an error back from the server if you check request.responseString?

You may need to add a value for the submit button, ie:

```
[request setPostValue:@"Sent" forKey:@"send"];
```

If that doesn't help, try using a proxy like [CharlesProxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to capture both a working request from the browser and the non-working iphone request, and compare them looking for any differences.

Comment: Yes, It was the missing piece! Thanks for the proxy, can be very useful.